# Alternatives to a deep inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: oop, inheritance, orm, language-agnostic, domain-driven-design

I am attempting to model products with a set of comprehensive attributes. Usually an online store would use a text description to list the attributes of a specific product. However, this solution is not optimal.

For example, the following links show the inconsistencies of attributes within a text description for the same product, but with different manufacturers:

- [MSI GTX690](http://www.landmarkpc.co.za/store/gtx690-n690gtxp3d4gd5-nvidia-geforce-p-8883.html)
- [Gigabyte GTX690](http://www.landmarkpc.co.za/store/gigabyte-gtx690-gvn690d54gdb-nvidia-geforce-p-8498.html)
- [ASUS GTX690](http://www.landmarkpc.co.za/store/asus-gtx690-gtx6904gd5-nvidia-geforce-p-8564.html)

Thus, I have opted for an inheritance hierarchy as follows:

`Product` > `Component` > `GraphicsCard` > `NvidiaGraphicsCard`

The reason for this is because I want fine-grained control over the attributes of each `Product`. This allows me to include attributes specific to say a `NvidiaGraphicsCard` that are not applicable to an `ATiGraphicsCard`.

Note that, in addition to adding more fields to subclasses, the inheritance allows me make use of polymorphism in terms of having an `OrderItem` hold a reference to a `Product`. This is a reason why I ruled out composition.

Is there a problem to having such a deep inheritance hierarchy, and if so are there any solutions or perhaps patterns to handle this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deep inheritance hierarchies are problematic in the context of DDD and ORMs for a few reasons.  One problem arises when you try to define an entity's identity. A `Product` must be comparable to other products based on identity, regardless which sub-class is being compared. This functionality can be provided in the `Product` class, but care must be taken to ensure that sub-classes can also be compared and there are a few gotchas. For example, NHibernate will generate a proxy for classes, so that actual runtime type of the object will not be `NvidiaGraphicsCard` but a proxy inheriting from it. While a transient instance of `NvidiaGraphicsCard` will not be a proxy. This means that you can't compare them based on type.

Another difficulty is in configuring ORM mappings to support inheritance. While most ORMs allow for it, the resulting mapping and generated SQLs are often complex. Do you store all sub-classes in a single table? In multiple tables with foreign keys to a common product table? In the former you end up with a huge table. In the latter case your queries will suffer since all sub-class tables will need to be joined. There is just too much of an impedance mismatch between the relational model and the object model. Event if using a document database, it is best to favor composition over inheritance.

Instead, I would go for having a single `Product` class, which can be composed of either product specific descriptors, or a dictionary of attributes. This would an `OrderItem` to reference a `Product` without knowing the specific product type - no need for polymorphism. This would also make it easier to allow for new types of products - no need to create a new sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

It's a school book example of inheritance, a good example. I see nothing wrong with such model, except that persisting it in relational database will be hard.

On the other hand sometimes a group of properties are only relevant to a subset of items that cannot be expressed via single inheritance. E.g. `PowerConsumption` describing how much power given product needs is not relevant for mice and USB sticks. Also weight is not really important for some components. This means you might investigate languages having traits, like Scala, to make your models as DRY as possible.

Note that there is no performance penalty of deep inheritance - longer inheritance chain doesn't mean slower virtual method calls (well, you won't use virtual calls a lot since these are just data containers).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at the Decorator pattern. This way you will have whatever finesse you need and less than a billion classes.